# Disable href of HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I disable an `href` based on data? Below, there is a table that will display the data. When the `Clik Here` is clicked, the data will be sent to the database.

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Button</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Mr.XX</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>Street XX</td>
       <td><a name=sendName id=sendId href="#" >Clik Here</a></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

However, when the `age` cell is not equal to 20, the `href` for `Click Here` should be disabled, so that the user cannot send that data to the database.

Comment: Can you please add more information (f.e. a jsFiddle). Is the table from php, asp or whatever? does the table always have only one entry? how will the age be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xcqv/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Mr.XX</td>
            <td>
                <input id="ageInput" type="text" value="20" />
            </td>
            <td>Street XX</td>
            <td><a name="sendName" id="sendId" href="#">Clik Here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ageInput').keyup(function (e) {
        var age = $(this).val();
        if (age != 20) {
            // anything what should happend if its not 20 f.e.:
            $('#sendId').hide();
        } else {
            // anything what should happend if it is 20 f.e.:
            $('#sendId').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you think you have to **downvote** it would be good to **leave a comment**.

Comment: I dont have idea why people downvote for this answer.This is almost what I want .Thanks for help :)

Comment: No problem. You asked you get the answer you needed -> everything i wanted ;)

Answer (score 1):

add `onclick="return false;"`

`<a name=sendName id=sendId href="#" onclick="return false;" >Clik Here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler for the link, get the age value, perform the test and simply return false from the handler if you dont want it to do anything (i.e. !== 20), else return true to persist the data...

Answer (score 0):

Try may be this:-

```
function disableLink()
    {
    if(document.getElementById(".age").innerHTML != 20)
    {
    document.getElementById('YourLink').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('YourLink').removeAttribute('href');    
    document.getElementById('YourLink').style.textDecoration = 'none';
    document.getElementById('YourLink').style.cursor = 'default';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but generally speaking using inline JS is terrible practice.

Comment: @PeeHaa:- Ok got your point.!!! Updated my answer with another option!!! Does this seems good ??:)

Comment: It is a request for downvoters if they can leave a comment for the reasoon for downvoting... **IT WOULD BE GREAT**

Answer (score 0):

if the data format is going to be consistent, you should add an `id` attribute to the table cell that will display the data. this way javascript can access it using the method `.getElementById()`

Comment: yes .that is what actually I do ,but I dont want to show the code here because it too long .So I just make a simple and easy to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JQuery?

```
$("#sendId").on("click", function(){
    if ($("#age").text() != 20) {
        return false;   
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvSQw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML5 validation:

```
<form>
    Mr.XX
    <input id="ageInput" type="number" value="20" min="20" max="20" />
    Street XX
    <input type="submit" name="sendName" id="sendId" value="Clik Here" />
</form>
```

If the age is not a number, or if it's less than 20, or greater than 20, the form won't be valid and the browser won't send it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xcqv/39/)

Answer (score -1):

Make it change the href to `javascript: void(0)` if the value is not 20

JSFIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/NBuxW/

Using JQuery:

```
if($(".age").text() != 20) {
    $('.my-link').attr("href", "javascript: void(0)");
}
```

Using Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById(".age").innerHTML != 20) {
    document.getElementById(".age").href = "javascript: void(0)"
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the negative vote the second I posted?

Comment: I hate it when people downvote a valid answer for no reason without explanation, luckily someone upvoted to 0 :(